# How to reset root password for a single mysql process

Tags: mysql

I need to reset a root password for one of my mysqld processes. I know in mysql, you can use mysqld_safe with the skip grant tables option, but what do you do when you have multiple mysql processes and want to reset their root user passwords? I can't use this option with mysqld_multi.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqld_multi` is basically just a collection of `mysqld` processes. So you can simply start that specific process manually with the skip grant tables option.

Do note that you have to stop the specific group with `mysqld_multi` first though.

Comment: How would I start a specific process with mysqld_safe?

Comment: @stevebot: start the server with the configuration you have in your `my.cnf`. You should have something like `[mysqldN]` where `N` is the specific configuration you want to run. Specifically the `datadir` option is very important.